# Existence proof for a random variable $X$ where $\operatorname{E}[X]$ exists, and $\operatorname{E}[X^2]$ doesn't

Tags: probability, random-variables, expectation

Can you think of a random variable $X$ where:
 $\operatorname{E}[X]$ exists, and $\operatorname{E}[X^2]$ doesn't?

I'm not sure if I remember correctly but I remember having heard in the lecture  that If $\operatorname{E}[X]$ exists, then we can use the alternative formula for the variance:

$$
\operatorname{Var}[X] =\operatorname{E}[X^2] - (\operatorname{E}[X])^2
$$

However, when reviewing my notes I realised that the precondition for using this alternative notation for the variance different: the precondition is that $\operatorname{E}[X^2]<\infty$ must hold (which implies that $\operatorname{E}[X]$ exists).

Is there a way to prove that:
$$
\operatorname{E}[X] \text{ exists}
\Longrightarrow
\operatorname{E}[X^2] \text{ exists}
$$
Or is there a counterexample where $\operatorname{E}[X]$ exists, and $\operatorname{E}[X^2]$ doesn't?

Comment: Yes there are counter-examples, like Pareto distribution with the appropriate parameter.

Comment: Would you regard $E[X^2]=+\infty$ as *existing*? If so, then there are examples where $E[X^2]$ exists but $E[X]$ does not.  If not, then there are examples where $E[X]$ exists but $E[X^2]$ does not

Comment: I don't think so ..

Comment: @Henry $X^2$ is a non negative measurable function. Therefore its integral always exist (in the sense it is well defined). However it can be infinity.

Comment: For example, Student's $t$-distribution with $2$ degrees of freedom. The expected value is then equal to $0$ and the variance is equal to $\infty$.

Comment: @Henry By existing i mean in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Cauchy distribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you may know
$$\mu = \mathbb{E}[X] = \int x p(x)$$
and
$$\sigma ^2 = \text{var}[X] = \mathbb{E}[X^2] - \mathbb{E}[X]^2 = \int x^2 p(x)-  \left( \int x p(x) \right)^2$$
and it is not valid in general the assertion
$$\mathbb{E}[X] \in \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow \mathbb{E}[X^2] \in \mathbb{R}$$
while the converse, namely
$$\mathbb{E}[X^2] \in \mathbb{R} \Rightarrow \mathbb{E}[X] \in \mathbb{R}$$
is always true.

In fact there exist an infinite number of probability distributions in which the mean is defined, while the variance is not: one is the [Pareto distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution), with parameter $\in ]1,2]$.

Comment: Thank you for the example!

Comment: you're welcome!